# Не могу вызвать метод start из класса x (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        x a = new x();
        a.start();

    }
}
```

//

```
package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class x extends MainActivity {

    public void start ()
    {

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("hello");
    }


}
```

Comment: Работать то нечего не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю такой вариант, иба вообще не вижу логики. Вы всё делаете не верно.

```
abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        init(savedInstanceState);


    }

    abstract void init(Bundle savedInstanceState);
}
```

Теперь в классе X опишите следующее.

```
 public class X extends MainActivity{

        @Override
        void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText("hello");
        }
    }
```